# Check the check box while entering the text in the text area of HTML editor?

Tags: jquery, html, extjs4

I need to check the check box while type the text inside the HTML editor.
The below code works fine when I click the source edit button on the HTML editor toolbar. After the all button disabled the check box is checked. Can anyone correct the code?

Here is extjs code:

```
this.mcmServiceIndicatorsOthCheckbox = new Ext.form.field.Checkbox({ fieldLabel: '', id: 'otherbox', boxLabel: 'OTH (must complete comments)' });

this.mcmServiceIndicatorsCommentsHtmlEditor = new Ext.form.HtmlEditor({
            height: 50,
            style: 'background-color: white;',
            enableSourceEdit : true,
            anchor: '100%',             
                listeners: {
                    afterrender: function(){
                      this.textareaEl.on('keyup', function() {
                         var notes = this.getValue(); 
                          if(notes.length > 0)
                          {
                              Ext.getCmp('otherbox').setValue(true);
                          }
                          else
                          {
                              Ext.getCmp('otherbox').setValue(false);
                          } 
                      });              
                    }
                }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add another event handlers for `change` event:

```
change: function () {
    Ext.getCmp('otherbox').setValue(this.getValue().length > 0);
}
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/Ld9Dj/1/

Comment: Thanks But in my project it won't work. after toggle the source edit only the check box function works. i need this when text lenght is > 0 or else the check box is not checked

Comment: Please help me. the check box is not checked after enter the text.

Comment: I tought I know what you asking for, but now I am confused. If you want checkbox to work in richtext edit mode like in source edit mode then use my answer. If no - you must write what you need in understandable manner otherwise it would be hard for me to help you.

Comment: when am type the text in the text area of the html editor, the check box is automatically checked otherwise it not checked. am use the length for check the length of the string after wards it check the check box.

Comment: this is the js file i have done.. if there is any code error let me know. Your corrected code works fine but during initialize it work automatically. http://jsfiddle.net/suresh1988/W8bCT/

Comment: When i type the text in the text area of html editor, the check box is automatically checked based on the text length. otherwise it uncheck the check box. Your code works but when on initialization the fuction happens, not on change the text in text area. i think its initially loaded